# Short_title character problem

Tags: functions, title

I am using this code to shorting the title:

```
function short_title( $after = '', $length ) {
    $mytitle = get_the_title();
    if( strlen( $mytitle ) > $length ) {
        $mytitle = substr( $mytitle, 0, $length );
        echo $mytitle . $after;
    } else echo $mytitle;
}
```

and i call it with:

```
<?php short_title( '...', 40 ); ?>
```

The script works fine but i am having character problem. [See the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niACk.png) Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mb_strlen()`, [not `strlen()`](http://wpengineer.com/2410/dont-use-strlen/).
The same with `mb_substr()` and `substr()`: Your title contains multi-byte characters, but `strlen()` and `substr()` do not work on characters, they work on single bytes.

For a improved function to shorten strings see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11085/truncating-custom-fields#11089).

Answer (score -1):

as the word is broken at the end, this problem is very likely. you can use the following snippet instead which will finish at word boundary

```
function short_title($after = '', $length)
{
  $mytitle = get_the_title();
  if (strlen($mytitle) > $length) {
    $mytitle = substr($mytitle, 0, $length);
    $i = strrpos($mytitle, " ");
    $mytitle = substr($mytitle, 0, $i);
    echo $mytitle . $after;
  } else {
    echo $mytitle;
  }
}

short_title( '...', 40 );
```

ref: http://code.web-max.ca/truncate_string.php

however, if you have/use multibyte support, probably it's better idea to use mb_strlen() & mb_substr(), mb_strpos() rather than strlen(), substr(), mb_strpos() function.