# Truncate latest activity in buddypress

Tags: buddypress

I'm using the buddypress hovercards plugin and Im dislaying some profile info as well as the latest status update. If a user posts a long status, it will run out of the hovercard div field. How can I properly truncate this?

```
<div class="update">
  <strong><?php _e("Last update", 'bp-hovercards'); ?></strong>
  <br>
  <?php bp_member_latest_update( 'length=10' ) ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter `'bp_get_activity_latest_update_excerpt'`. Sample code, not tested, you will need my [function `utf8_truncate()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11089/73):

```
add_filter( 'bp_get_activity_latest_update_excerpt', 'wpse_56860_trim_buddypress_excerpt' );

function wpse_56860_trim_buddypress_excerpt( $excerpt )
{
    // Number of characters to show. Adjust this to your needs.
    $length = 80;

    // Fix BuddyPress’ wrong quotes.
    return _x( '&#8220;', 'opening curly double quote' ) 
        . utf8_truncate( $excerpt, $length )
        . _x( '&#8221;', 'closing curly double quote' );
}
```

[Download as complete plugin](https://gist.github.com/3014422).

### Update

There is an alternative: create a `hovercard.php` in your theme, the plugin will use this file then instead of the same named file in the plugin directory. In `hovercard.php` change the line `bp_member_latest_update( 'length=10' )` to get the proper length or add the filter at the top of the file and remove it after the last `endif;`:

```
<?php if ( bp_has_members( "include={$_POST['userid']}&max=1") ) : 
add_filter( 'bp_get_activity_latest_update_excerpt', 'wpse_56860_trim_buddypress_excerpt', 8 );
?>
// lots of stuff
<?php endif; 

remove_filter( 'bp_get_activity_latest_update_excerpt', 'wpse_56860_trim_buddypress_excerpt', 8 );
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I would love to give this a try but I don't know where to place it. Can you please tell me where in my php files to place these snippets? Do I put them in my theme's functions.php or the plugin's php or..?

Comment: See my update. You can download the complete code as a plugin and install it on your blog.

Comment: I've uploaded it into my plugins folder but can't see it in the plugins list. Is that supposed to happen? Also, I need to only truncate the activity that is shown in a certain plugin (hovercards plugin)

Comment: Hm, it should be visible. Did you save [the raw file](https://raw.github.com/gist/3014422/e33616c80af9939191f21fce8a783395522c1469/bp-last-activity-shortener.php) as `bp-last-activity-shortener.php`?

Comment: Well yes but that is inside of a folder. Should I upload it to plugins without a folder?

Comment: Should not matter. Try it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3924/discussion-between-aliyah-and-toscho)