# excerpt in characters

Tags: excerpt, characters

I have code in functions.php:

```
function string_limit_words($string, $word_limit)
{
  $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
  if(count($words) > $word_limit)
  array_pop($words);
  return implode(' ', $words);
}
```

but i need to limit excerpt in number of characters,
could you help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this code in one of my last projects:

```
function ng_get_excerpt( $count ){
  $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID );
  $excerpt = get_the_content();
  $excerpt = strip_tags( $excerpt );
  $excerpt = mb_substr( $excerpt, 0, $count );
  $excerpt = mb_substr( $excerpt, 0, strripos( $excerpt, " " ) );
  $excerpt = rtrim( $excerpt, ",.;:- _!$&#" );
  $excerpt = $excerpt . '<a href="'.$permalink.'" style="text-decoration: none;">&nbsp;(...)</a>';
  return $excerpt;
}
```

I got it from here:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/limit-excerpt-length-by-characters

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923955/make-function-that-limits-text-not-show-last-punctuation-mark

It has the advantage of not allowing punctuation on the end and ending with the last complete word

Using the filters as suggested by [@medhamza7](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/285110/22534) or [@bainternet](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69438/22534) or [@fuxia](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69442/22534) is preferable.

Comment: Very thanks for this advice, efficient one for me is just simple: "echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,30);" taken from Your links.

Comment: @Marcin [`substr()` will break](http://wpengineer.com/2410/dont-use-strlen/). Never use it on UTF-8 encoded data.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has a filter for that which is conveniently named excerpt_length and it accepts a number of chars so:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 50;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

change 50 to whatever limit you want.

Update per @toscho comment:

that is the solution above is for words as well and not for chars so here is a quick one:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt','excerpt_char_limit');
function excerpt_char_limit($e){
    return substr($e,0,50);
}
```

Comment: That’s not for characters, it is for words.

Comment: @toscho My bad! updated with a simple solution

Comment: How does it works? i put it as "echo custom_excerpt_length(); " but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but how to give some excerpts lengths for front page?

Comment: @Bainternet - I gave: "add_filter('the_excerpt2','excerpt_char_limit2');
function excerpt_char_limit2($e){
    return substr($e,0,10);
}" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use the function [`utf8_truncate()` from this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11089/73) and fight your way through `wp_trim_excerpt()`.

Sample code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'wpse_69436_excerpt_more' );

function wpse_69436_excerpt_more( $more )
{
    add_filter( 'wp_trim_excerpt', 'wpse_69436_trim_excerpt' );
    // we remove the more text here
    return '';
}

function wpse_69436_trim_excerpt( $excerpt )
{
    return utf8_truncate( $excerpt, 300 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a better way, you can use the `get_the_excerpt` filter:

```
function get_excerpt($excerpt="",$limit=140){

    $excerpt = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
    $excerpt = mb_substr($excerpt, 0, $limit);
    $excerpt = mb_substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
    $excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
    $excerpt = $excerpt.'...';
    return $excerpt;
}   
add_filter('get_the_excerpt',"get_excerpt");
```

Change the `$limit=140` to the number of characters you want. Also if you want in different way:

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt',function ($excerpt="",$limit=140){

    $excerpt = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
    $excerpt = mb_substr($excerpt, 0, $limit);
    $excerpt = mb_substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
    $excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
    $excerpt = $excerpt.'...';
    return $excerpt;
});
```

That will make avoid any conflict like existing name of function `get_excerpt`.

Comment: @Nicolai i think we should avoid using `mb_substr`  cause some php config by default doesn't activated mb functions :/

Comment: As read [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11089/22534), WP has a fallback for it.