# Get the title before comma

Tags: php, functions

I am using this code to return the title of the post on a gravity form field.

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_page_name', 'page_name_filler');
    function page_name_filler($value){
        return get_the_title() ; 
    }
```

However, usually the title of the post is too long and it overfills the field. Hence I would only like to retain the first portion of the title before a comma "," if it exists on the title. Usually I will have multiple commas on my titles.

If a comma doesn't exist then the full title should be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`strtok()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php):

```
return strtok( get_the_title(), ',' );
```

You could also use my [function `utf8_truncate()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11089/73). This is a little bit more flexible and it can handle long strings without a comma.