# Get the the title of Wordpress after comma

Tags: php

I've read that you can get the title before comma(,)
[Get the title before comma](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166250/get-the-title-before-comma)

but wondering how can I get the title **after** comma(,) ?

is it also possible to use strtok()?
or are there similar function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use in this way

```
<?php
$sTitle =  "Your, Title";// From get_the_title(); or other sources
if(strpos($sTitle , ",")){
    $sTitle = substr($sTitle , strpos($sTitle , ",") + 1);    
} 
echo $sTitle; // You can also trim($sTitle); to remove whitespaces left from substr()
?>
```

Comment: glad i could help